# How to explain hidden/undocumented properties off of SObjectType?

Tags: apex

In a [recent question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/210840/how-to-pass-schema-sobjecttype-to-a-class-method-as-an-argument), I learned about seemingly magic variables/properties off of certain classes, such as `SObjectType.Account`, and `SObjectType.Custom__c`.

I also learned that if you have a method expecting an argument of type `DescribeSObjectResult`, you can pass in one of these magic properties, like `SObjectType.Account` and the Apex compiler is happy to accept it. It appears that somehow Saleasforce knows that it should call the `getDescribe()` method if one is passing in `SObjectType.Account`. Even then that doesn't make sense to me because `getDescribe()` is a member method of `SObjectType` based on the docs.

Also, from what I can tell, there's no documentation describing all the magic properties off of `SObjectType`. If you reference the docs for this class, it shows a messily [4 methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_class_Schema_SObjectType.htm).

How is one supposed to know about the magic `Account` property off of `Schema.sObjectType`?

Why is it possible to pass `Schema.sObjectType.Account` as an argument in a method expecting `DescribeSObjectResult`?

Comment: I'd recommend avoiding adding memes to your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:

```
System.debug(Schema.SObjectType.Account instanceof Schema.DescribeSObjectResult);
```

Result:

> Operation `instanceof` is always true since an instance of `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult` is always an instance of `Schema.DescribeSObjectResult`

---

`Schema.SObjectType` is a generic type for the sake of having a generic type, which is why theres methods you can use to interact with it. Somewhere in the compiler, apex is smart enough to replace:

```
Schema.SObjectType.Account
```

With:

```
Account.SObjectType.getDescribe()
```

I'd think of it less of a magic variables/property, and more like an enum, which returns a type, which also has a generic base type.

You need the other methods for generic or unknown at compile time types. Having a generic type to use when you run something can be a real lifesaver:

```
SObjectType accountType = Schema.getGlobalDescribe().get('Account');
```

From the base generic type, you can call `accountType.getDescribe()` to get the actual describe.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So `Schema.SObjectType.Account` doesn't actually exist, and the compiler creates `Account.SObjectType.getDescribe()` instead? How are we supposed to know this? Is there a list of compile-time translations for this and other classes/methods?

Comment: Pretty much, yeah. Stuff like `@isTest`, "`Account` type binds to `Schema.Account` when namespace is null or empty"  (from [apex winter '18 compiler changes](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000264742&type=1&language=en_US)).. I'm sure theres a lot more, but a lot of it is under the hood, and not usually discussed - you'd have to talk to someone at salesforce to get the full scope of the compiler. If you want to learn more, check this video out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Yc5FrviQqO8